# How to compare a certain value against Firebase child values?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

## Description

I'm using the Realtime Database with Google's Firebase, and I'm trying to check if a child value is match with a certain value.

[image]

I have a collection of **users** that I store in Firebase database.
Each user object contain a token field.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-LTTvwvs5OMaKO6pyZb-" : {
      "accountId" : 1001,
      "createdAt" : "2018-12-11 15:22:55",
      "email" : "john@doe.com",
      "fcmToken" : "duhfkNCIKW8:APA91bGgbzVCcagIhIw8DYFN_LVIKcjtyUiZEk0mxd3QLYkxRjQuGXdSfZMPcvw4maytKef-GXMEFrpH_lLz5QY0OV7qvwtyOll9jjKMH0vEWJUGIyp1iGQ4NZIMQE3kmZ-jZ8kF-1Bc",
      "updatedAt" : "2018-12-11 15:22:55"
    },
    "-LTTwH8BdMe6W1lmhb-b" : {
      "accountId" : 1001,
      "createdAt" : "2018-12-11 15:24:22",
      "email" : "john@doe.com",
      "fcmToken" : "e_86qbjpjLE:APA91bHyVEgeH8aZMrn7213ws0-oXeTpdFRwY-FDcAbkQkMnaCdSNp9he6-AvQ0AUIsX-TywAxuWLCZ9BqIRsuyx1ZD9reD6wMeqtfP1swONq-rF6vQzet61DUbLfPXdlZhvxEjI9Cpz",
      "updatedAt" : "2018-12-11 15:24:22"
    },
    "-LTTwNcoaQYri1paUwVD" : {
      "accountId" : 1001,
      "createdAt" : "2018-12-11 15:24:48",
      "email" : "john@doe.com",
      "fcmToken" : "e_86qbjpjLE:APA91bHyVEgeH8aZMrn7213ws0-oXeTpdFRwY-FDcAbkQkMnaCdSNp9he6-AvQ0AUIsX-TywAxuWLCZ9BqIRsuyx1ZD9reD6wMeqtfP1swONq-rF6vQzet61DUbLfPXdlZhvxEjI9Cpz",
      "updatedAt" : "2018-12-11 15:24:48"
    },
    "-LTUv-aBEaQDrvvMrlAG" : {
      "accountId" : 1001,
      "createdAt" : "2018-12-11 18:58:25",
      "email" : "john@doe.com",
      "fcmToken" : "eOaNDdd2DXI:APA91bGzgcudlScng9TuEgSUY9ahA2pXVgl7AKxmkdX9ubw6uA5livNcJUlcI5pHYwn9fI7kc_9od5AbGrXm4wZPul_gI7qcGarTQTwkxq9zEKgovX0nWDDpDtNCLiWIaON6MWu5XLbW",
      "updatedAt" : "2018-12-11 18:58:25"
    }
  }
}
```

---

## iOS Swift 4

On the other hand, on my phone, I have **1 token**

Ex.

> "duhfkNCIKW8:APA91bGgbzVCcagIhIw8DYFN_LVIKcjtyUiZEk0mxd3QLYkxRjQuGXdSfZMPcvw4maytKef-GXMEFrpH_lLz5QY0OV7qvwtyOll9jjKMH0vEWJUGIyp1iGQ4NZIMQE3kmZ-jZ8kF-1Bc"

I’m trying to compare that token  to all the tokens in my Firebase database.

---

## Code

```
func storeToFirebaseDatabase() {
    
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let usersRef = ref.child("users")
    
    let id = usersRef.childByAutoId().key
    let fcmToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "fcmToken")
    
    consoleLog(fcmToken)
    
    let values =
        ["accountId": loginAccount.id!,
         "email": loginAccount.username,
         "fcmToken": fcmToken
            ] as [String : Any]
    
    ref.root.child("users").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        
        if snapshot.exists() {
            
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let token = (child as! DataSnapshot).childSnapshot(forPath: "fcmToken").value as! String
                
                if(token != fcmToken){
                    
                    usersRef.child(id!).setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                        if err != nil {
                            print(err.self as Any)
                            return
                        }
                        print("Successfully saved user in Firebase DB")
                        
                    })
    
                    break
                }
                
            }
        
        } 
        
        
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

---

## Result

For some reasons, token are continuing inserting, seem like my if-check is working at all.

How would one go about debugging this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question but it appears that you want to create a user if a given token does not already exist in Firebase.

A simple query would allow that;

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
let tokenToCompare = "duhfkNCIKW8APA9..." //abbreviated
let query = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "fcmToken").queryEqual(toValue: tokenToCompare)
query.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        print("token exists, do not create user")
        return
    } else {
        print("no existing token found, create user")
    }
})
```

If the token exists, it will print that message and not continue. If the token does not exist, you can then insert the code to create the user.

...and if you want to get all denormalized, then add a separate node to keep track of the existing tokens

```
existing_tokens
   jasoijaisas9: true
   99i9kmkdodkf: true
   duhfkNCIKW8APA9: true
```

then you can avoid the heavier query with a simple observe which is much lighter weight.

```
let existingTokensRef = self.ref.child("existing_tokens")
let tokenToFindRef = existingTokensRef.child("duhfkNCIKW8APA9")
tokenToFindRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if !snapshot.exists() {
        print("ok to create user")
    } else {
        print("token exists! Dont create user")
    }
})
```

The only thing to watch with this technique is not having [special characters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) in the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `setValue` you can use a HashMap() with `updateChildValues`, it will override if the token is different, and if it's equal, it will not update the token and override the current one.

And you prevent querying your database to get that value and compare it with an if statement.

You should replace this line with `updateChildValues` instead of `setValue`

```
usersRef.child(id!).setValue(values....
```

Take a look here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

From the documentation

> To simultaneously write to specific children of a node without
>   overwriting other child nodes, use the updateChildValues method.
>
> When calling updateChildValues, you can update lower-level child
>   values by specifying a path for the key.

Comment: You suggest that we should not query just to check the comparision - Am I understand you correctly?

Comment: when you use updateChildValues, it will go to your desired child to set the token value, if the value already exists it will not overrride it or update it, if the value exists but its different than the one you want to set , it will update the current value without overriding it

Comment: I understand, and I will use `updateChildValues`, but how do I know which child value to update if I don't check each one all the way to the bottom ?

Comment: .child(id!) will do the job, since you are accessing each userID , updateChildValue will update or not if they are different

Comment: Ok, with that said, I already used the code you suggested in the answer. Am I missing something else ? : https://i.imgur.com/etYKUsr.png

Comment: As I sugested you should not use .setValue , instead you should use updateChildValues, but you will need a map to set it to the reference, check the documentation it explains how its done, Im more an Android guy than IOS but I think the solution is the same for both plataforms, since the logic does not change

Comment: ahh got it. I confused by your advice in your answer. You pointed out my mistake, but I thought that you suggest the answer --- that was the confusing part. I got you now. Sure, will do ... looking at the documentation now.

Comment: also , when you replace setValue with updateChildren, delete this lines since you dont need to bring the user tokens or either compare them. ---> let token = (child as! DataSnapshot).childSnapshot(forPath: "fcmToken").value as! String

                if(token != fcmToken){

Comment: Sure will do, but can you please update your answer with some code I will try those right the way.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you compare the token inside the if statement with each user , but you need to see if a user has it or not

```
ref.root.child("users").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if snapshot.exists() {

      let tokens =  snapshot.children.forEach { ($0 as! DataSnapshot).childSnapshot(forPath: "fcmToken").value as! String }

        if ! tokens.contains(fcmToken) {

             // no user has that token ,  set the user here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I know for sure that my user object will always have the fcmToken column.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion toward my existing code ? You also think I should use `updateChildValues ` ?

Comment: your requirement is to be sure that there is no user has that same fcmtoken before adding  ? if so , then the above is sufficient